# Data set for Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks

I am using Regression with Neural Networks and I want to set my train and test dataset.
But I have a huge dataset in Excel that obviously do not have the shape that Mathematica requires.
If I understand, Mathematica wants this format:

{173.15, 0.4496, 384.95, 41.25}-> 0.1167

In the bracket, there are the inputs and the output is after the arrow

But I have my dataset in this way
{0.1167, 173.15, 0.4496, 384.95, 41.25}.

So how can I transform my dataset to feed the network?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Rest[#]->First[#] & /@ dataset`

Comment: It works! Great. Thanks a lot